# Firefox can't access to the internet, but everything else can

Tags: networking, wireless, updates, internet

I don't see why I can't access the internet when I run Firefox in Ubuntu 13.10.

I was previously able to until I resolved an issue where the software updater gave me a repository download error. Now the message is gone, the updater works fine, but the internet connection does not even work when it says I am connected to the WiFi.

What's wrong? Is a re-install the only viable option? I don't have any data on it.

Comment: what was the output of `ping -c 2 google.com`

Answer (score 0):

If you can connect with other software such as chromium then I think the easiest thing is to try a re-install!

But following on from Avinash, if there is no problem with your connection then I would suggest a reinstall. You have no data required? Well you could try another browser and forget about firefox, or open the terminal and type `sudo apt-get remove firefox`

Then to try again just type `sudo apt-get install firefox` I am not saying you do not know how to do this, I just included this for anyone else having the same problem and wanted aid. Hope this helped you! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and fixed it by resetting/refreshing Firefox settings. 
You should type `about:support` on your firefox address bar and select the `Refresh Firefox` button at the top right of the window.

The instructions on how to do this are available here https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/refresh-firefox-reset-add-ons-and-settings

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu, while this link may answer the question, it's better to include the essential parts here.